# SCSS Change sibling color on hover

Tags: css, sass, menu, hover, siblings

I have a menu where I want to change the link color on hover, but also change all of its  siblings to another color. Is this possible without JS?

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>lorem</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>ipsum</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

SCSS:

```
ul {
    $primary-color: orange;

    > li {
        > a {
            color: #000;
            border-bottom: solid 2px transparent;

            &:hover {
                color: $primary-color;
                border-color: $primary-color;

                & + a:not(:hover) {
                    color: red;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not affect the other `a` tags when one is hovered. Your only real option here is to apply the "other" colour when the `ul` is hovered, and then override the "other" colour when the link is hovered.

```css
ul > li > a {
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: solid 2px transparent;
}
ul > li > a:hover {
  color: orange;
  border-color: orange;
}

ul:hover a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>lorem</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>sit</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>amet</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

SCSS version: https://codepen.io/3rror404/pen/OJMNyJg

Comment: Thanks a lot, hadn't crossed my mind that I could just go up one level..

Comment: Adding `ul { width: max-content }` may be helpful to add to the effect here. But honestly I would use JavaScript instead of CSS here.

Comment: @Daan I just added `ul { display: inline-flex; }`. But thanks for the contribution, might be helpful for someone :)